# Method rangeOfCharacterFromSet not working if there is Single Symbol

Tags: ios, objective-c

Method `rangeOfCharacterFromSet` is not working if there is single Symbol

> NSCharacterSet.symbolCharacterSet

```
[@"Kamleshwar!" rangeOfCharacterFromSet:NSCharacterSet.symbolCharacterSet]
```

In case I will put space or two Symbols`(Kamleshwar !) or (Kamleshwar!#)` then it works as expected

Comment: Neither # nor ! are in the `symbolCharacterSet`

Comment: Then # and ! comes under which category. Isn't these Special Characters. But when I put both then same code working fine

Comment: They're in the `punctuationCharacterSet`.

Answer (score 0):

I got answer hope this can help someone. We can set our own range and check.

```
NSString *specialCharacterString = @"!~`@#$%^&*-+();:={}[],.<>?\\/\"\'";
NSCharacterSet *specialCharacterSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:specialCharacterString];
```